# Office 365 GatewayTimeout error / the preferred replica is unavailable

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, office365, office365api

I'm attempting to run the Office 365 Starter Project for ASP.NET MVC and following the readme here...

https://github.com/OfficeDev/O365-ASPNETMVC-Start/blob/master/README.md

I'm click the "Register your app" link in the add connected service dialog. I sign in and see the message "Registering the directory application..." Then after about a minute, I get the error message "Office 365 GatewayTimeout".

After a search turned up nothing, I restarted Visual Studio as admin and after the same process got the error "the preferred replica is unavailable"

Has anyone come across/resolved this error?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by moving the directory to my drive root. It turns out that some names in this particular project were too long for Visual Studio.